# Cruzar información de dos o mas stored procedures

Tags: sql

Buen día:

Necesito ayuda para resolver lo siguiente, estoy tratando de cruzar información de 2 SP en el primero obtengo existencia de un listado de productos y el en segundo el costo de los productos ambos a una fecha determinada.

El primero es asi

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ExisIncial 
@fechaInicio date
AS
BEGIN
SELECT        dbo.Inventarios.ProductoID, SUM(CASE WHEN Kardex.TipoMovimiento IN (1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14) 
THEN Kardex.Cantidad * - 1 ELSE Kardex.Cantidad END) AS ExisInicial
FROM            dbo.Inventarios INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Kardex ON dbo.Inventarios.IdInventario = dbo.Kardex.ItemInventarioID
WHERE        (dbo.Inventarios.AlmacenID IN (1, 2, 6)) AND (dbo.Kardex.Fecha < @fechaInicio)
GROUP BY dbo.Inventarios.ProductoID
END
```

*

El segundo es así:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ CostoInicial
@fechaFinal date
AS
BEGIN
SELECT        IdProducto,
                             (SELECT        TOP (1) dbo.Kardex.CostoUltimaEntrada
                               FROM            dbo.Inventarios INNER JOIN
                                                         dbo.Kardex ON dbo.Inventarios.IdInventario = dbo.Kardex.ItemInventarioID
                               WHERE        (dbo.Inventarios.ProductoID = dbo.Productos.IdProducto) AND (dbo.Inventarios.AlmacenID IN (1, 2,6))
   AND (dbo.Kardex.Fecha < @fechaFinal)
                               ORDER BY dbo.Kardex.Fecha DESC) AS CPUE_Final
FROM            dbo.Productos
END
```

Lo que me arrojan es

```
ProductoID ExisInicial  
14 0.00
16 0.00
31 2189.00
33 792.00
46 0.00
48 194.00
50 157.00

IdProducto CP_Inicial
14 0.250
16 5.510
31 701.160
33 2244.520
46 1.130
48 0.850
50 0.710
```

Al unirlos o intentar cruzar las dos consultas me da los resultados en tablas separada, lo que quiero realizar es

```
ProductoID  ExisInicial CP_Inicial
14  0   0.25
16  0   5.51
31  2189    701.16
33  792 2244.52
46  0   1.13
48  194 0.85
50  157 0.71
```

Me podrían orientar para saber como hacerlo.

Gracias

Comment: Cuando dices que intentas cruzar las consultas, ¿qué intentaste exactamente?

Comment: Mande llamar los 2 sp desde otro con un Union

Comment: Y qué te sale? Procura siempre añadir esa información en las preguntas. Muestra el código que intentas usar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mejor sería que hicieras un nuevo procedimiento que traiga ambos datos sin tener que leer múltiples veces las tablas.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CostoExistenciaInicial(
    @fecha date
)
AS
WITH cte_Costo_Existencia AS(
    SELECT i.ProductoId,
           CASE WHEN k.TipoMovimiento IN (1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14)  THEN k.Cantidad * - 1 ELSE i.Cantidad END AS Cantidad,
           k.CostoUltimaEntrada,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY i.ProductoId ORDER BY k.Fecha) AS rn
    FROM       dbo.Inventarios AS i
    INNER JOIN dbo.Kardex      AS k ON i.IdInventario = k.ItemInventarioID
    WHERE      i.AlmacenID IN (1, 2, 6)
    AND        k.Fecha < @fecha
 )   
SELECT  i.ProductoID, 
        SUM(Cantidad) AS ExisInicial,
        SUM( CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN CostoUltimaEntrada END) AS CPUE_Final
FROM cte_Costo_Existencia
GROUP BY ProductoID;
```

También es importante señalar que el uso de nombres de 3 partes en las columnas será eliminado en una versión futura de SQL Server. Para evitar usarlas, tenemos los alias.